# Why did the henchmen leave a harmonium in the street?

Tags: plot-explanation, punch-drunk-love

In Punch-Drunk Love (2002), Barry Egan witnesses a bizarre car accident and a car stops and a henchman leaves a harmonium in front of him and leaves. He picks up the abandoned harmonium from the street.

Why did the henchmen leave the harmonium in the street?